# CFDB plugin : Preventing Duplicate Submissions from CF7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form where user add his email address, I’m trying to prevent users to enter there email many times. I use "contact form to database plugin" to save email address and export them to excel. while searching on internet I found this solution (link below) but I can’t get it work can you help me please :

https://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=904

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, 
in the line where you put the name of the form you should put the title of the form (line bellow ) :

```
 $formName = 'email_form'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
```

so, for exemple if we have created with the contact form 7 a form here is the shortcode that we will have :

```
  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="69" title="Email_form" html_name="my_form"]' ); ?>
```

what I did is I put the value of html_name in the script of CFDB but when I changed to the value of title it works